# Tool to verify that each public class has javadoc comment

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Please propose some tool to verify that each public class and member has javadoc comment. I'm using IDEA to edit source, but haven't found a options to make javadoc essential.

Thank you very much.

Comment: **check style** (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html) would be your obvious option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool such as [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) do exactly that, among many other checks. You can use it to produce a full report with many different checks for your codebase.

It is common to use it along with bytecode based analysis tools, such as [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) or [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), that are used to detect some coding errors, such as dead code, erroneous null checks, and many more.

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ IDEA can checkt it for you. You have to enable Javadoc inspections.
You can set various parameters. Like check only public classes, members and methods.

[image]